# Wordpress Permalinks not working even with mod_rewrite enabled

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, wordpress, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set up my local Wordpress instance for development. I've changed the permalinks to `http://localhost/localwp/%postname%/` and my `.htaccess` file was updated successfully:
[screenshot of the permalinks screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxAEA.png)

`.htaccess`

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /localwp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /localwp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Well, this just don't works. I've been searching and found issues about mod_rewrite being disabled, so I made sure mine one was properly enabled on `/etc/sysconfig/apache2` (weird path, but its the default at the distro I'm using). Also `phpinfo()` confirms that the mod is enabled.

Even with mod_rewrite enabled I keep getting 404 when I try to access any post, even using the "View" button on WordPress. e.g: `http://localhost/localwp/pagina-exemplo/` (pagina-exemplo is portuguese for example-page, and its created automatically by Wordpress).

If it matters, there is some more details I extracted from phpinfo:

```
Apache API Version  20120211
Loaded Modules  core mod_so http_core prefork mod_unixd mod_systemd mod_actions mod_alias mod_auth_basic mod_authn_core mod_authn_file mod_authz_host mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_core mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cgi mod_dir mod_env mod_expires mod_include mod_log_config mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_setenvif mod_ssl mod_socache_shmcb mod_userdir mod_reqtimeout mod_version mod_php7 mod_rewrite
```

My distro is OpenSuse Tumbleweed 20190428

Answer (score 1):

I fixed by adding

```
<Directory /srv/www/htdocs/localwp>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to my `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file. Where `/srv/www/htdocs/localwp` is where is located my Wordpress files